# 'SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON' Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, pdo

Eu estou utilizando o Laravel 5.4 com 2 conexões, uma delas é apenas para acessar algumas Views de um banco Sql Server, e uma delas faz um LINKED SERVER o que me obriga a setar umas configurações antes de fazer uma consulta.

Eu consigo hoje fazer da seguinte forma no meu Controller:

```
$busca = DB::connection('meuhost');
$busca->statement('SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON');
$busca->statement('SET ANSI_PADDING ON');
$busca->statement('SET ANSI_NULLS ON');

$select = $busca->select('SELECT top 100 * FROM nome_da_view ');
```

Assim funciona perfeitamente, mas eu não gostei de trabalhar dessa forma, portanto criei uma Model para acessar essa View que está da seguinte forma:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class NomeDaModel extends Model
{
    // 
    protected $connection = 'meuhost';

    protected $table = 'nome_da_view';

}
```

E no Controller:

```
$busca = NomeDaModel::get();
```

Já tentei setar utilizando `setAttribute`, statement, exec, nada funcionou.
O erro ocorre no PDO:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7405 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [7405] (severity 16) [(null)]
```

Mas já sabemos o que precisa ser setado na conexão para resolver esse erro, só preciso saber a forma correta de fazer isso na Model ou na Controller que não seja da forma que funcionou logo acima.

Comment: Para resolver o problema sem a necessidade se setar as configurações a cada consulta, pode-se colocar isso na Model:

    protected $statement = ['SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON', 'SET ANSI_PADDING ON', 'SET ANSI_NULLS ON'];